# Python 3 List: How do I sort [('NJ', 81), ('CA', 81), ('DC', 52)] base on number and then letters?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

If my list is
`[('IL', 36), ('NJ', 81), ('CA', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39)]`,

how can I sort it so that my result will be
`[('CA', 81), ('NJ', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39), ('IL', 36)]`?

Comment: .. or "How to sort list of 2-tuples descending on the second element, then ascending on the first element?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty straight forward:

```
your_list.sort(key=lambda e: (-e[1], e[0]))
```

for example

```
>>> your_list = [('IL', 36), ('NJ', 81), ('CA', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39)]
>>> your_list.sort(key=lambda e: (-e[1], e[0]))
>>> your_list
[('CA', 81), ('NJ', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39), ('IL', 36)]
```

Note that the above sorts the list in place.  If you want to wrap this in a function and not modify the original list, use `sorted`

```
def your_sort(your_list):
    return sorted(your_list, key=lambda e: (-e[1], e[0]))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you didn't have the convenience of being able to `-somefield`, then the Pythonic approach would be to do a multi-phase sort that takes advantage of Python's sort being stable.

```
a = [('IL', 36), ('NJ', 81), ('CA', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39)]

from operator import itemgetter
a.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
a.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
# [('CA', 81), ('NJ', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39), ('IL', 36)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the first element if it is not equal, if equal compare the second element. If you want in reverse order, switch `cmp(a, b)` for `cmp(b, a)`.

```
>>> a = [('IL', 36), ('NJ', 81), ('CA', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39)]
>>> sorted(a, cmp=lambda x, y: 
                      cmp(y[1],x[1]) if x[1]!=y[1] else cmp(x[0],y[0]))
[('CA', 81), ('NJ', 81), ('DC', 52), ('TX', 39), ('IL', 36)]
```

The other answer is shorter, but this approach works even if one of the elements is not numeric and can be extend for any number of levels, although you may want to write a proper comparison function instead of using lambda - for a generic N-level sort:

```
>>> def arbitrary_level_tuple_sort(iterable, order=[(0, 'a')]):
        def comparator(a, b):
            for i, o in order:
                if a[i] != b[i]:
                    if o == 'a':
                        return cmp(a[i], b[i])
                    else:
                        return cmp(b[i], a[i])
            return 0
        return sorted(iterable, cmp=comparator)

>>> arbitrary_level_tuple_sort(a, [(1, 'd'), (0, 'a')])
[('CA', 81), ('NJ', 81), ('NJ', 81), ('TX', 39), ('IL', 36)]
```

The `order` argument is a list of tuple indexes and orders (a=ascending/d=descending), this works for tuples of any size:

```
>>> b = [tuple([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)]) for i in range(5)]
>>> b
[(7, 5, 5, 8, 0),
 (0, 4, 5, 0, 7),
 (7, 4, 0, 9, 0),
 (1, 1, 3, 9, 4),
 (6, 2, 9, 6, 3)]
```

Sort by the 4th element (index 3) descending, then for the 5th and first ascending:

```
>>> arbitrary_level_tuple_sort(b, [(3, 'd'), (4, 'a'), (0, 'a')])
[(7, 4, 0, 9, 0),
 (1, 1, 3, 9, 4),
 (7, 5, 5, 8, 0),
 (6, 2, 9, 6, 3),
 (0, 4, 5, 0, 7)]
```