# Sorting a List of Elements by the First element but if Equal sort by the second

Tags: python

I have constructed a list `[[13, "b"], [10, "b"], [10, "a",], [4,"c"], [1, "d"]]` which is sorted by the first value in the list of two elements.  That is the part I can do.  What I don't know is if two elements are the same, then I want to sort it alphabetically.  The method I used to sort the first list was reversing a sorted list by the first element.  This however makes `[10, "b"]` come before `[10, "a"]` but i want "a" before "b".  Is there a way to write sort by first element in descending order and if a tie, sort alphabetically by the second element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3 List: How do I sort \[('NJ', 81), ('CA', 81), ('DC', 52)\] base on number and then letters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711598/python-3-list-how-do-i-sort-nj-81-ca-81-dc-52-base-on-number)

Answer (score 22):

This works:

```
>>> li=[[13, "b"], [10, "b"], [10, "a",], [4,"c"], [1, "d"]]
>>> sorted(li,key=lambda sl: (-sl[0],sl[1]))
[[13, 'b'], [10, 'a'], [10, 'b'], [4, 'c'], [1, 'd']]
```

The [sorted function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) produces a new list. You can also sort the list in place using the sort method:

```
>>> li=[[13, "b"], [10, "b"], [10, "a",], [4,"c"], [1, "d"]]
>>> li.sort(key=lambda sl: (-sl[0],sl[1]))
>>> li
[[13, 'b'], [10, 'a'], [10, 'b'], [4, 'c'], [1, 'd']]
```

You can also do a nested sort (or sort on one key, then the second key) since python uses a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> li=[[13, "b"], [10, "b"], [10, "a",], [4,"c"], [1, "d"]]
>>> li.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
>>> li
[[10, 'a'], [13, 'b'], [10, 'b'], [4, 'c'], [1, 'd']]
>>> li.sort(key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)
>>> li
[[13, 'b'], [10, 'a'], [10, 'b'], [4, 'c'], [1, 'd']]
```

Since there is no need for a lambda in a one element sort, I used the faster [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) vs a lambda. Whether two faster sorts are faster than one, I don't know... You can also use a lambda for this method.

There is a great [sort tutorial](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) that shows many of these idioms.

Comment: +1 for faster typing :) here's mine `sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))`